# Can I set the time when toolTip appears on QGraphicsItem?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qgraphicsitem

Good afternoon. The toolTip on QGraphicsItem appears after about one second. Can this value be changed?
If so, how?

Comment: Do you want to set the different timeout for each item or do you want everyone to have the same timeout?

Comment: It would be ideal to set everyone to 10 minutes, but the option with different times for each object is also interesting, because I am studying this.

Comment: _It would be ideal to set everyone to 10 minutes_ Seriously?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can give a try using

```
void QToolTip::showText(const QPoint &pos, const QString &text, QWidget *w, const QRect &rect, int msecDisplayTime)
```

You need to handle the `QEvent::ToolTip` in your event handling code. I lifted that piece of code from documentation. And below it is. (Note: I did not test this.)

```
//CREATE AN EMPTY RECT
QRect rect();

//HANDLE THE QEvent::ToolTip
if (event->type() == QEvent::ToolTip) {
        QHelpEvent *helpEvent = static_cast<QHelpEvent *>(event);
        int index = itemAt(helpEvent->pos());
        if (index != -1) {

        //HERE YOU CAN CONTROL TIME.
            QToolTip::showText(helpEvent->globalPos(), shapeItems[index].toolTip(), nullptr,rect,<<TIME YOU WANT TO SET>>);
        } else {
            QToolTip::hideText();
            event->ignore();
        }

        return true;
    }
    return QWidget::event(event);
}
```